# Creating a SQL string to use with exec sp_executesql @sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having difficulty formatting a string to be used with `SP_executesql`. I keep getting the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 144
>   Incorrect syntax near '))'

Line 144 is the last line of this code

All variables were declared above

```
set @Sql = @Sql + ' select distinct provider_id, ' + @changestring  + ',       null,''' 
    + 'case when ' + @changestring +  '= 6 then ds.excldate +
     else   +

    CONVERT(varchar(20),' + GETDATE() + ') end  as '+ '''Effective_Date' 
    + ''', null,1,' + @username + ''' 
     +  ,NULL,' + CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE()) + ''','''  + CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE()) + ''', '''+ @username + '''' +
    ' from ( 
    select distinct provider_id
    FROM provider pv WHERE provider_id In (select Provider_id from dbo.##sanctiontermswid  )) ds 
    where ds.provider_id not in (
    select provider_id from provider_status ps  where ps.provider_id in (
    select distinct provider_id
    FROM Provider pv WHERE provider_id IN (select Provider_ID from  ##sanctiontermswid ) and ps.provider_status_type_id = ' + @changestring + '))'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forgetting to convert the first GETDATE() to varchar.

Comment: I think the error my be in this piece of code 'select distinct provider_id FROM Provider pv WHERE provider_id IN (select Provider_ID from  ##sanctiontermswid ) and ps.provider_status_type_id = ''' + @changestring + '''))'

Comment: Hmm I changed the first GETDATE() to "CONVERT(VARCHER(20), GETDATE())" and got no errors. The resulting string didn't look right, but you should be able to make changes from there. Just add "SELECT @Sql" at the end so you can see the results and make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to finally format my SQL. The problem was in formatting the case statement.

```
set @Sql = @Sql + 'select distinct DS.provider_id, ' + @changestring  + ',              null, case when ''' + @changeString + '''!= ''6'' then '''  
        + CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE()) + ' '' else CONVERT(DATE,DS.exCldate) end as ''Effective_date'''
        + ', null,1,'''+ @username + '''
         ,NULL,''' + CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE()) + ''','''  + CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE()) + ''', '''+ @username + '''' +
        ' from (
        select distinct PV.provider_id, T1.EXCLDATE
        FROM provider pv 
        JOIN dbo.##tmpSanctions T1 ON PV.PROVIDER_ID=T1.PROVIDER_id
         ) ds
        where ds.provider_id not in (
        select provider_id from provider_status ps  where ps.provider_id in (
            select distinct provider_id
            FROM Provider pv WHERE provider_id IN (select Provider_ID from     dbo.##tmpSanctions ) and ps.provider_status_type_id= '+ @changestring + ' and ps.effective_thru is null))'
```